# Aardvark I2C slave nack issue

Tags: python-2.7, flash, i2c, slave, eeprom

I followed the steps in this link: [Using the Aardvark with Python on 64-bit Windows](http://www.totalphase.com/support/articles/201158087-Using-the-Aardvark-with-Python-on-64-bit-Windows)

I have tried to write and read bytes using command prompt (Write and read from the EEPROM using aai2c_eeprom.py) i.e. when attempting to read by typing:
`C:/Python27/python.exe aai2c_eeprom.py 0 300 read 0x51 1 4`.
I have observed that I can write to EEPROM but I cannot read any bytes from EEPROM. It prints:

> *error: no bytes read – are you sure you have the right slave address?*

Does anyone know why I am getting this error message?

**Note**: I am using Microchip Technology's 24LC024 EEPROM. You can see the datasheet via this link: [I2C Serial EEPROM](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21210G.pdf). According to this datasheet the slave address is calculated as 0x51. Hence, I don't know why I am getting slave address error.

Besides, when I checked it with the Total Phase's Flash Center SW, I obtained an Read Error:

> *Adapter: Slave NACK.*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. The problem was occurred because I had 2 master devices that attempt to control the bus at the same time. Hence, it corrupted the message. As written in this link: [Master Read](http://www.totalphase.com/support/articles/200468316-Aardvark-I2C-SPI-Host-Adapter-User-Manual) "The Aardvark adapter was unable to seize the bus due to the presence of another I2C master. Here, the arbitration was lost during the slave addressing phase"